# Simple MYSQL Query Question

Tags: mysql, join

```
    SELECT t.thread_id, t.subject, u.username,
    COUNT(p.post_id) - 1 AS responses, 
    MAX(DATE_FORMAT(p.posted_on, '%e-%b-%y %l:%i %p')) AS last,
    MIN(DATE_FORMAT(p.posted_on, '%e-%b-%y %l:%i %p')) AS first
    FROM threads AS t
    INNER JOIN posts AS p USING (thread_id)
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE t.cat_id = 1
    GROUP BY (p.thread_id) ORDER BY last DESC
```

I thought I did this right, however my query is only returning one row, I have 4 rows where t.cat_id = 1. Any ideas?

EDIT**
SAMPLE DATA
http://i56.tinypic.com/f1e449.png

Right now im only getting just one result:

```
1  THREAD1  USER1  8  17-Apr-11 6:22 AM  17-Apr-11 3:58 AM
```

I was expecting to get something like:

```
1  THREAD1  USER1  8  17-Apr-11 6:22 AM  17-Apr-11 3:58 AM
2  THREAD2  USER1  8  17-Apr-11 6:22 AM  17-Apr-11 3:58 AM
3  THREAD3  USER1  8  17-Apr-11 6:22 AM  17-Apr-11 3:58 AM
```

Comment: Can you post sample data, the expected result and actual result?

Comment: maybe all 4 rows have the same p.thread_id, you do a group by on it

Comment: Added the sample data :) I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that there are no corresponding rows in one of the join tables:

```
INNER JOIN posts AS p USING (thread_id)
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```

Another possibility (not mutually exclusive of the first) is that the grouping clause collapses the rows.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand it last night but messing around I found our what I needed was a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You have selected t.thread_id, yet you group by p.thread_id.

Change the `group by` into

```
GROUP BY (t.thread_id) ORDER BY last DESC  
          ^
```